# Pandoc \Diamond Symbol Not Working With Subscript

Tags: symbols, pandoc

I'm trying to convert a book to word format (or at least get a passable first attempt) using pandoc and the book frequently uses the symbol \Diamond in equations.  However, pandoc's output gives garbage whenever that symbol is subscripted.

Here is test code of a file and a screen shot of the resulting output

```
\documentclass[11pt,leqno]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\begin{document}

\( \Diamond \phi \) 


\( \Diamond_{\phi} \psi \iff \Box_{\phi} \phi \) 

\end{document}
```

And here is what is produced after running: pandoc test.tex -o test.docx (latest word for OS X)

[image: pandoc-result]

Note that it works fine without a subscript Is there any way to redefine/replace \Diamond with some other symbol that pandoc will handle?  Other solutions?

(\diamond seems to work better but produces much too small a symbol).

Comment: This seems to be a font problem. If I change the font in word to `LibertinusMath` the diamond is displayed correctly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is (somehow, obscurely) a problem with Word's default math font.¹ Change the font in Word and the diamond will be displayed correctly:

**Fira Math**

[image]

**Libertinus Math**

[image]

Another solution is converting to `.odt` with `pandoc test.tex -o test.odt` and opening the resulting file with Word:

[image]

---

1. Maybe it is a problem caused by pandoc's docx-writer, that is fixed by changing to another font...

Comment: Thanks!!  You don't happen to know how to change the font used in all the equations in a doc ...I see how to do it an equation at a time but I’m not finding a general way.

Comment: In theory, you can change the defaults of a `.docx` file and use it as a template with pandoc (option: `--reference-doc=FILE`). But I don't know, how to change the math font in word globally either.

Comment: well thanks anyway...now that I know it's just a font issue this can probably just be dumped on the stupid publisher who insisted on word for my wife's philosophy book that has a giant pile of theorems in it...I’m sure they use their own fonts anyway.

Comment: Math works better, if you convert the file to `.odt` and open the resulting file with word... Also, try [tex4ht](http://tug.org/tex4ht/) instead of pandoc, it's better suited for larger projects like books

Comment: Thanks for the rec.  I was leaning away from tex4ht because it turns all the equations into images and I don't think it does refs correctly for theorems but that might be useful to replace the equations that can't be converted.

Comment: @PeterGerdes TeX4ht doesn't need to produce images for math, it depends on options you use. The best results can be achieved using MathML and MathJax. You can try it using `make4ht test "mathml,mathjax"`.